# How to create a stateful Groovy Binding for interactive Session

Tags: java, groovy

I am building a groovy-based tool and as an add-in i'd like to provide an interactive command-line, I have this partially working but the binding doesn't keep state between `GroovyShell.evaluate()` calls, I've gone through the groovy documentation and they have an example using a class called `InteractiveGroovyShell`, which is not available on version 2.0.x.

Is there a way to configure normal groovy shell to achieve this functionality?

Here is a simplified version of how I'm creating the groovy shell right now:

```
CompilerConfiguration config = new CompilerConfiguration();
Binding binding = new Binding();
shell = new GroovyShell(binding, config);
shell.evaluate("def a = 20");
shell.evaluate("println a"); //this throws an exception telling the variable does not exist
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
shell.evaluate("def a = 20");
```

Instead of `def a = 20` you need just `a = 20`. Each `evaluate` call parses and compiles a separate script, and declarations (whether with `def` or with an explicit type such as `int a = 20`) become local variables in that specific script and do *not* store anything in the binding. Without the `def` you have a plain assignment to an otherwise undeclared variable, which will go into the binding and so be visible to later `evaluate` calls.

Answer (score 0):

You should reuse the same `binding` for different shells. The binding itself will maintain the state:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilerConfiguration

def binding = new Binding()
def shell = new GroovyShell(binding)

shell.evaluate("a = 5")
assert binding.variables == [a:5]

shell.evaluate("println a; b = 6")
assert binding.variables == [a:5, b:6]

def shell2 = new GroovyShell(binding)

// even in a new shell the binding keep the state
shell2.evaluate("c = 7")
assert binding.variables == [a:5, b:6, c:7]
```

Worked in groovy 2.0.5

Comment: Have you tried running this code? I always run evaluate with the same instance of the shell and actually this is what is not working for me.